# Is this an imperative sentence?

Tags: conditionals, imperatives

Is this sentence an imperative sentence, or does it have conditional meaning?

> You hang around with riffraff like the Weasleys and that Hagrid, and it’ll rub off on you.

Comment: Both clauses are indicative, although the meaning is conditional. Spoken English has a relaxed rule-set. It would appear that J K Rowling's work may not be the best text-books for learning English.

Comment: It is conditional insofar as this is: “If you do this, then I will do that.”

Comment: Why the down votes? This is actually a pretty interesting question. It is an informal conditional statement that elides the "if" at the beginning of the sentence, substituting an "and" conjunction to start the final clause. It is worthy of examination.

Comment: @Robusto: to piggyback on your thought, the sentence could also be subtly modified, and become an imperative: _You hang around with riffraff like the Weasleys and that Hagrid, and I'll stay in the chat room with FumbleFingers and Dumbledore._

Comment: I agree. It's a very interesting question. I once published [a paper on the subject](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/conics.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler: Perhaps you could sum up your findings as an answer here. I'm sure it would become the canonical answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a complex situation.

Sentences like the presenting one are clearly intended to urge, if not impose, some kind of behavior on the addressee (though the addressee in this case is only a generic *you*, the same sense as *one*, but faluting a couple levels lower).

So in that they are like imperatives. However, it can be shown (as I do in [my paper](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/conics.pdf)) that they aren't real imperatives, syntactically. They must be a different construction, mimicking an imperative. It's clear that the construction **does** have some conditional meaning --

- (***If***) you hang around with riffraff like the Weasleys and that Hagrid,
- (***Then***) it’ll rub off on you.

which is the beginning of a *Modus Ponens* [syllogism](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf):

- ((p Implies q) And p) Implies q  | ((p ⊃ q) ⋀ p) ⊃ q

The second line is implied in context, and the conclusion follows.

An extreme case of this is

- *Buy 10 and Save!* (almost always with an exclamation point)

which means something like (boldfaced omissions)

- ***If you** buy 10 **`[count noun]`s, then you will** save **some money.***

Comment: Or ["Touch me and I'll scream!"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Touch+me+and+I'll+scream%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) - also almost always with an exclamation point!

Comment: Canonical. (When was John canonised?)

Answer (score 5):

It could conceivably be read as an imperative (or, more correctly, an *impositive* as John Lawler explains in the comments):

> [Go and] hang around with riffraff like the Weasleys and that Hagrid, and it’ll rub off on you.

But given the context, it's unlikely that the speaker meant it as a command. (After all - who would command someone to go get bad influences from riffraff?)  It's more likely to be interpreted as a conditional:

> [If] you hang around with riffraff like the Weasleys and that Hagrid, <strike>and</strike> it’ll rub off on you.

Comment: The cover term is "Impositive"; it's meant to impose something on someone.

Comment: @JohnLawler: You mean "Impositive" versus "Imperative"?   I'll admit I was just quoting back the question title, perhaps incorrectly.

Comment: _Imperative_ is a specific syntactic category, with its own syntax, while _impositive_ is a term that covers true imperatives, suggestions, noodges, rants, and any other attempt to impose some behavior (or lack of behavior) on a person. So this **is** an impositive, but it **isn't** an imperative.

Comment: @JohnLawler What is the syntactic formula to form an imperative sentence?

Comment: I can describe them, but not give a "syntactic formula to form" them. I don't know what kinds of "formula" you mean. True English imperatives have uninflected (i.e, infinitive form) action verbs and a second person subject (which is usually deleted). E.g, _Get out of here. Take your box with you. You stand over there. Be honest, now. Have a good time. Enjoy yourself/yourselves/*himself/*myself._