# Interpretation of phrase with imperative

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, imperatives

I want to clear up the usage of imperative in the following sentence:

"Come here to earn a coffee."

Is this sentence equivalent to "if you come here then you will get a coffee"?

Comment: Yes. It's not an imperative; it's [a hypothetical clause mimicking an imperative](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/mimicry.pdf). It's used a lot in advertising because credulous people will obey without thinking.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate (certainly answered and involving 'a hypothetical clause mimicking an imperative') (but here with a rather different [implicit subject] hypothetical clause) of [Is this an imperative sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90710/is-this-an-imperative-sentence/90736#90736).

Comment: It depends on whether you have to do something other than just show up (like fill in a market research form) in order to get the free coffee.

Comment: @BoldBen Even if that's required, it's still not an imperative. It's more of a prerequisite.

Comment: @Barmar To be honest I hadn't noticed the word 'imperative' in the question. I was concentrating on the difference between 'earn' which implies that you have to do something to gain a reward and 'will get' which implies an unearned gift.